# How to run multiple database on neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to connect Multiple standalone Neo4j instances on a single machine.

As I am not able to find the right documentation to installed Neo4j properly.

Since I am new to Neo4j graph db, It would be very helpful if someone can help me on this.

I am using Neo4j version 3.2.2

Below is the command I tried to start new neo4j instance under the path `/usr/share/neo4j`:

```
sudo bin/neo4j start -path /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph1.db -config /etc/neo4j/neo4jtest.conf -run /usr/share/neo4j/run/neo4jtest.pid -log /usr/share/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log
```

I couldn't able to start the two neo4j instance since I have two `neo4j.conf` files which has different ports.

Please kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advised to do this, but if you want to do so, the easiest way is to work with the zip install (not with a package install, you're bound to forget something that'll come to haunt you). Unzip, make as many copies of the resulting folder as you need and in each of them change the http, https and bolt ports in neo4j.conf so they don't conflict. Also make sure to explicitly assign memory to each instance. Then launch them each from their own directory ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

P.S. The above procedure is tested as in fact it is the starting point for setting up an Enterprise cluster on one host.